# label does not appear on xamarin app android device

Tags: c#, xamarin

the label appears in the emulator but does not appear on android devices, how is the solution?

I use the default code

Here's the trailer

```
<Label Text="Start developing now" FontSize="Title"/>
```

Comment: Show the activity class. Looks like space issue

Comment: Hi Shalahudin! What is the code of the rest of the page? Can you try changing the `BackgroundColor` of the Label? Just to check if it's the same color (due to the device's theme)

Comment: @JuanSturla, thank you, now solved, because I use a black hp theme, so the text automatically becomes white so it's the same as the background.

Comment: @ShalahudinAlAyyuby that's great to hear! Then I'll write that as answer, and if that's Ok with you, you can mark it as correct. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the configuration of the emulator and the configurations of the device are different.

Because of that, sometimes the default color of some components depend on the `Theme`.

A good way to check this is changing the `BackgroundColor` of the Label? Or the `TextColor` or the `BackgroundColor` of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `FontSize` property can be set to a double value directly, or by a NamedSize enumeration value

```
<Label Text="Font size 24"
   FontSize="24" />
<Label Text="Large font size"
   FontSize="Large" />
```

Check the documentaion [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts)

Also you can inspect by changing the background color